# Found "ModuleNotFoundError" when running the code "from skimage import data" on Window 7

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, scikit-image

I am getting an error - "ModuleNotFoundError" at the code "from skimage import data" using python 3.7 default IDE editor with window 7. Using Jupyter notebook, it worked fine. I've already installed Python followed with pip install scikit-image. How to fix?

My script:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

from skimage import data
```

The error:

> ... traceback ...

Comment: post the traceback error for context around the error. Now its kinda vague "ModuleNotFoundError"! Also add version of skimage and matplotlib.